# AngularJS: Reset form on submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm using an AngularJS form for a contact form and would like to reset the form on successful submission. I've found plenty of examples of how to reset an AngularJS Form and have that working, however, I've been unable to figure out a way to successfully reset the form on submission. My reset() function clears the form fields and appears to set the state of the form back to pristine when called on submit, however, the messages that should only be shown when a field is invalid are still displayed.

Here's my controller code with the function...

```
function ContactCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.reset = reset;
  vm.submit = submit;


  function reset(form) {
    if (form) {
      vm.name = undefined;
      vm.email = undefined;
      form.$setValidity();
      form.$setPristine();
      form.$setUntouched();
    }
  }

  function submit(form) {
    if (form) {
      vm.reset(form);
    }
  }
}
```

The full code can be found below or on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RqOwQahZIJoaGcDByoFn?p=preview)

```js
angular
  .module('plunker', [])
  .controller('ContactCtrl', ContactCtrl);

function ContactCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.reset = reset;
  vm.submit = submit;


  function reset(form) {
    if (form) {
      vm.name = undefined;
      vm.email = undefined;
      form.$setValidity();
      form.$setPristine();
      form.$setUntouched();
    }
  }

  function submit(form) {
    if (form) {
      vm.reset(form);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ContactCtrl as contact">
  <form name="form" novalidate>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.name" name="uName" required="" />
    <br />
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uName.$touched">
      <div ng-show="form.uName.$error.required">Tell us your name.</div>
    </div>

    E-mail:
    <input type="email" ng-model="contact.email" name="uEmail" required="" />
    <br />
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched">
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
    </div>

    <input type="button" ng-click="contact.reset(form)" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="contact.submit(form)" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <pre>
    FORM:
    form.$pristine = {{form.$pristine}}
    form.$dirty = {{form.$dirty}}
    form.$submitted = {{form.$submitted}}
    
    NAME:
    form.uName.$pristine = {{form.uName.$pristine}}
    form.uName.$dirty = {{form.uName.$dirty}}
    form.uName.$valid = {{form.uName.$valid}}
    form.uName.$invalid = {{form.uName.$invalid}}
    
    EMAIL:
    form.uEmail.$pristine = {{form.uEmail.$pristine}}
    form.uEmail.$dirty = {{form.uEmail.$dirty}}
    form.uEmail.$valid = {{form.uEmail.$valid}}
    form.uEmail.$invalid = {{form.uEmail.$invalid}}
    
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's probably because after you reset the form, the blur event on the field is going to be fired and triggers the form validation.

Comment: That's what I noticed as well. If your form is valid, it works correctly, however; if there's an error in the form, the validation runs and doesn't trigger the `ngClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could put the function you want to run on-submit inside of an `ng-submit` directive, this appears to get executed the same as the reset button:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="contact.submit(form)">
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,  adding ng-submit

```
<form name="form" novalidate ng-submit="contact.submit(form)">
```

It worked for me.

Your button should look like this now

```
 <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also found that if you want to still use the form submit instead of ng-submit event, you need to wrap your form clearing code in a `$timeout` function. This forces the code you stick inside the $timeout to execute 'synchronously' to any other event actions (in this case the form submit).

[Modified Plunkr seen here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yma8vKXmpVXUoSdFe4OQ?p=preview)

```
angular
  .module('plunker', [])
  .controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout', ContactCtrl]);

function ContactCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.reset = reset;
  vm.submit = submit;
  vm.resetMe = resetMe;


  function reset($event, form) {
    if ($scope.form) {
      $timeout(function(){
        vm.name = undefined;
        vm.email = undefined;
        $scope.form.$setValidity();
        $scope.form.$setPristine();
        $scope.form.$setUntouched();        
      });
    }
  }

  function submit(form) {
    if (form) {
      vm.reset(form);
    }
  }

  function resetMe(){
    console.log($scope);
    debugger;
    $scope.form.$setPristine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! That makes sense. Thanks.